# How to catch the exception in the right way? [beginner]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, exception, try-catch

There is the following function, which doesn't catch MyException.

```
const myFunction = () => async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    myHTTPRequest().then(async (response) => {
      if (response.data.results.length != 1) {
        throw new MyException('MyError');
      }
      res.end('All good');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      throw error; //Doesn't work
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('This block should catch MyException, but it doesn't');
    next(error);
  }
};
```

Instead, the application writes following error message into the console

```
(node:45746) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning
(node:45746) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:45746) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The question is, how does the code need to be adjusted to catch MyException in the expected Catch-Block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you're mixing `.then/.catch` with `try/catch`.

If you want the code to enter the `try/catch` in an `async` function, you have to use the `await` keyword on the `Promise`.

You can drop the `.catch` since it's doing nothing, you're throwing again the error, and that's causing the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`

```
const myFunction = () => (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const response = await myHTTPRequest();

    if (response.data.results.length != 1) {
      throw new MyException('MyError');
    }
    res.end('All good');

  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

Using `.then/catch` without `async/await` the code would be:

```
const myFunction = () => (req, res, next) => {

    myHTTPRequest().then((response) => {
      if (response.data.results.length != 1) {
        throw new MyException('MyError');
      }
      res.end('All good');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      throw error;
       // It makes no sense to throw again in here
       // But I'm showing you how to handle it if you do
    })
    .catch(error => {
        next(error);
    })
};
```

Of course the double `.catch` doesn't make sense, and you should remove it, leaving a single one:

```
const myFunction = () => (req, res, next) => {

    myHTTPRequest().then((response) => {
      if (response.data.results.length != 1) {
        throw new MyException('MyError');
      }
      res.end('All good');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        next(error);
    })
};
```

Comment: Great reply.  You should change the `console.log` message to represent the new situations.  Otherwise TLDR; readers may miss your points.